# Angular docs Expressions - plunker example not working with current workable version

Tags: angularjs, plunker

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

The simplest example using data bindings =

```
<span>
  1+2={{1+2}}
</span>
```

works with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

and the output is 1 + 2 = 3

but if I change to the current workable angular script

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.25/angular.js"></script>
```

the output is 1+2={{1+2}}

So why does the current angular not allow this simple data binding example to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.25/angular.js return 404 page
So, please use another version of angular.

Comment: That is weird because that is the script that Plunker uses when the add package button is clicked! so when I use <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script> it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

your script should be like this

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.25/angular2.js"></script>
```

if you want to know about more working version of angular then visit this

---

[list of Angular working Version](https://code.angularjs.org/)